# WPF list modification during iteration?

Tags: wpf

[image]

I'm trying to make a very simple game where the yellow ball bouncing back and fourth. If it collides with one of the moving blue squares, the square is supposed to disappear and a new one should appear (always 3 in the window) elsewhere. When my code reaches this part, all 3 squares disappear (then reappears as intended it is not a problem) and I just cant figure out why. It would be a huge help if somebody could run over my methods responsible for the problem. Thank you in advance.

So my timer_Tick method, responsible for every frame:

```
 void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            logic.MoveBall();
            if (model.Enemy.Count<3)
            {
                logic.AddEnemy();
            }

            int iii = 0;
            foreach (MyShape enemy in model.Enemy)  //the whole thing from here is me trying to solve list modification during iteration
            {
                if (logic.MoveEnemy(enemy) == -1)
                {
                    logic.MoveEnemy(enemy);
                }
                else iii = logic.MoveEnemy(enemy);
            }
            if (iii > -1)
            {
                for (int j = model.Enemy.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    if (j == model.Enemy.Count - iii)
                    {
                        model.Enemy.RemoveAt(j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

MoveEnemy: I try to decide whether there is collusion and if yes, then try to remove the given shape object (blue square). Because This whole method is in a foreach, I just save the removable element and forward it to timer_Tick

```
public int MoveEnemy(MyShape shape) 
{
    int i = 0;
    int ii = -1;
    if ((shape.Area.IntersectsWith(model.Ball.Area)))
    {
        i = 0;
        foreach (var e in model.Enemy)
        {
            i++;
            if (shape == e)
            {
                ii = i;
            }

        }

    }

    shape.ChangeX(shape.Dx);
    shape.ChangeY(shape.Dy);
    bool coll = false;

    foreach (var e in model.Enemy)
    {
        if ((e.Area.IntersectsWith(shape.Area)) && (shape != e))
        {
            coll = true;
        }
    }

    if (shape.Area.Left < 0 || shape.Area.Right > Config.Width-40 || coll)
    {             
        shape.Dx = -shape.Dx;              

    }

    if (shape.Area.Top < 0)
    {
        shape.Dy = -shape.Dy;
    }
    if (shape.Area.Bottom > Config.Height/2)
    {
        shape.Dy = -shape.Dy;              
    }

    RefreshScreen?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    return ii;

}
```

And finally AddEnemy:

```
public void AddEnemy()
        {
            rnd = new Random();
            int r = rnd.Next(-300, 300);
            model.Enemy.Add(new MyShape(Config.Width / 2+r, 0, 40, 40));
            RefreshScreen?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

Comment: WPF is very cool. Did you also consider using Unity? It have a lot of features specifically built to do this. https://unity.com/

Comment: For anything more complex I agree, but WPF should do the trick in this case I think.

Comment: `foreach` uses enumerators ([IEnumerator<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1?view=netframework-4.8)). Modifying the collection the enumerator was retrieved from (`foreach` internally calls `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`), won't update the enumerator and the iteration would become unpredictable. If you want to iterate over a collection and modify it at the same time use the index based `for`.

Comment: Ty, I will try it with for

Comment: Wait, I'm already using "for" for the modification in timer_Tick.

Comment: Elsewhere I use foreach to iterate list and save the index what I will remove outside the foreaches with "for"

Comment: If all you want to do is to remove the item which collides with the ball from the `model.Enemy` collection your code can be havily simplified which would surely eliminate the bug. I don't understand what you are doing in the for-loop with the `j` index decrementation. But never mind. Let me post a simplified implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>` (or `IList` and `Enumerable`) exposes some useful methods to compact code:

```
int itemIndex = list.IndexOf(item); // Gets the index of the item if found, otherwise returns -1
list.Remove(item); // Remove item if contained in collection
list.RemoveAll(item => item > 5); // Removes all items that satisfy a condition (replaces explicit iteration)
bool hasAnyMatch = list.Any(item => item > 5); // Returns true as soon as the first item satisfies the condition (replaces explicit iteration)
```

A simplified version, which should eliminate the flaw:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (model.Enemy.Count < 3)
  {
    logic.AddEnemy();
  }

  logic.MoveBall();
  model.Enemy.ForeEach(logic.MoveEnemy);    
  model.Enemy.RemoveAll(logic.IsCollidingWithBall);
}

public void AddEnemy()
{
  rnd = new Random();
  int r = rnd.Next(-300, 300);

  model.Enemy.Add(new MyShape(Config.Width / 2 + r, 0, 40, 40));

  RefreshScreen?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

public bool IsCollidingWithBall(MyShape shape) 
{
  return shape.Area.IntersectsWith(model.Ball.Area);
}

public int MoveEnemy(MyShape shape) 
{
  shape.ChangeX(shape.Dx);
  shape.ChangeY(shape.Dy);

  bool hasCollision = model.Enemy.Any(enemy => enemy.Area.IntersectsWith(shape.Area)  
    && enemy != shape);

  if (hasCollision  || shape.Area.Left < 0 || shape.Area.Right > Config.Width - 40)
  {             
    shape.Dx = -shape.Dx;              
  }

  if (shape.Area.Top < 0)
  {
    shape.Dy = -shape.Dy;
  }

  if (shape.Area.Bottom > Config.Height / 2)
  {
    shape.Dy = -shape.Dy;              
  }

  RefreshScreen?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed!